# preg_match , only works locally

Tags: php, regex

This is the code that works, locally.

```
$str = <<<SSS
  <H1 class="prodname">Alison Raffaele Reality Base</H1>Foundation, Skintone 1 - Fairest&nbsp;1 fl oz (30 m)<p class="tip"><table id="TblProdForkSellCopy" width="100%" border="0"><tr><td class="contenttd"><p>Get full, flawless coverage with this luxurious oil-free formula. Continually refreshes and re-hydrates your skin for 12+ hours - and guards against premature aging by deflecting damaging free radicals. </p></td></tr></table><p></p>
SSS;

preg_match("~</[hH]1>(.+?)<p~",$str,$name)  ;
var_dump($name) ;
```

But doesn't work when the page is actually parsed. Why ? Link to the [page](http://www.beauty.com/alison-raffaele-reality-base-foundation-skintone-1--fairest/qxp184230?catid=179216) . 
Is there anything wrong with my code. I have copy pasted exactly from the page.
Oh and by doesn't work I mean it matches too much. When matched locally the first `'<p'` isn't included , but in my actual script (when the page is downloaded from the net) it includes the `'<p'` tag for some reason.

Thanks

Comment: "But doesn't work when the page is actually parsed" < what do you exactly mean by that? parsed?

Comment: I mean when I try to parse it with the regex . fetch page with curl > make simple html dom  doc > parse it with regex.

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you insane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Comment: You speak the truth, Truth. It has driven me quite insane..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/<h1[^>]*>([^<]+)/i
```

It's not working because you're closing the tag ignoring the HTML tag attributes.
See the `[^>]*` it will match to all before(the attributes) `>`, as the `class="prodname"` part of your example. 
See the `i` flag. will not differentiate case. Can match`h` and `H`.